# Transaction (Process ID 59) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am deleting records the following way :-

```
string deleteWrongEntry = "DELETE FROM [" + schemaName + "].[Entry] WHERE CompanyId=" + companyId + " AND EmployeeId = " + StrECode + " AND Entry_Date = '" + StrInputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(deleteWrongEntry);
```

This code is in foreach loop & runs more than 2000 times.

I am getting the following error :-

> Transaction (Process ID 59) was deadlocked on lock | communication
>   buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the
>   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

In the Stack trace, i get the following :-

> --at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   --at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    --at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    --at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    --at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    --at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    --at
>   Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    --at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1
>   operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1
>   executing, Action`1 executed)    --at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    --at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    --at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass57.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__55()
>   --at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    --at
>   Greytrix.Pocket.Data.TimeOffice.TimeOfficeInOutProcess.SaveTimeEntry(String
>   schemaName, Int32 companyId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
>   --at Greytrix.Pocket.Data.TimeOffice.TimeOfficeInOutProcess.InOutImportProcess(String
>   schemaName, Int32 companyId, DateTime fDate, DateTime tDate, Boolean
>   flagAutoShift, Boolean flag)    --at
>   TimeOffice.Controllers.UtilitiesController.InOutImport(FormCollection
>   form, String Command)

What is solution for this?

Can i just put a try catch block for this 2 lines so that code will atleast run further & will skip only that record which is affected?

Comment: what is the need for the loop

Comment: That is the Business Logic. I have just pasted the relevant code.!